# In React, method returning cannot read property 'target' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

The parent component contains the method handleBlur and the child component has an input field which triggers the method handleBlur in the parent. Every time when I type something to the field, it's always failing and returning me the error "**TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined**
"

method in parent:

```
handleBlur = e => {
  console.log("e: ", e);
  const { name, value } = e.target;
}
```

input field in child:

```
<Input
  id="amount"
  title="Required: Amount"
  name="amount"
  value={amount}
  handleBlur={this.props.handleBlur}
  handleChange={(name, value) =>
    this.props.handleChangeOnDollarAmount(name, value)
  }
/>
```

Comment: Did you make sure to pass `handleBlur` among props within parent component to the child component holding that input? Like `<ChildHoldingInput handleBlur={this.handleBlur} ... />`

Comment: Also, are you sure the issue is with `handleBlur`? The signature for `handleChange` seems strange.

Comment: "Every time when I type something to the field, it's always failing and returning me the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined "" sounds a lot more like a `handleChange` problem...

Answer (score 1):

The blur event does not fire until you leave the field. Since the error is happening "Every time when I type something to the field", the issue is most likely not in the `handleBlur` function.

It appears that your `handleChange` has an incorrect signature.

Change it to accept an event, and use the event to get the `name` and `value` properties.

```js
handleChange={(e) => {
  this.props.handleChangeOnDollarAmount(e.target.name, e.target.value)
}}
```